# Python boxplot on single variables

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, statistics, boxplot

I'm trying to print all the boxplots for each variable in a dataset with this python loop.

```
colNameList = list(df.columns)
for i in range (0, len(df.columns)):
    df.boxplot(column=colNameList[i])
```

Where df is my dataset.

Why this simple code shows to me only the last one boxplot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a separate plot for each variable, just put the plt.show() inside the for loop:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

for i in df.columns:
    df.boxplot(column=i)
    plt.show()
```

You can write your code in a more pythonic way: df.colums is already a list and the iteration is done on the list

Comment: what is plt? @Joe

Comment: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt is a library

Comment: I can't sorry, my reputation is very bad. I'm new here @Joe

Answer (score 6):

IIUC, you want a box for each column, which is the default for [`df.boxplot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.boxplot.html).

**Example dataframe**:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':np.random.randint(0,9,100),
                   'col2':np.random.randint(2,12,100),
                   'col3':np.random.randint(4,14,100)})

>>> df.head()
   col1  col2  col3
0     6     9     4
1     5     2     8
2     0     7    11
3     0    10     9
4     0     3     8
```

**Plotting:**

```
df.boxplot()
```

[image]

If you want just certain columns:

```
df[['col1', 'col2']].boxplot()
# or
df.boxplot(column=['col1', 'col2'])
```

[image]

**Edit** Based on your comments, here is a way to save each individual box as a separate boxplot, so you can see them individually.

```
for i in df.columns:
    df.boxplot(column=i)
    plt.savefig('plot'+str(i)+'.png')
    plt.close()
```

Comment: if I want to do it in a loop and show it for each variable?

Comment: Do you mean a separate plot for each variable?